# unable to get data in datatable using mvc structure in php

Tags: php, model-view-controller, datatables

I want to fetch data in datatable.I think the problem is ajax source URL.
the error is "datatables warning : JSON data from server could not be parsed this is caused by a json formatting". i have tried calling model and controller file using @URL.Action.

**slider.js**

```
datatable = $("#dynamic-table").dataTable({
    "bAutoWidth" : false,
    "bFilter" : true,
    "bSort" : true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide" : true,
    "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
            "sProcessing": "<img src='"+root_domain+"img/loading.gif'/> Loading ...",
            "sEmptyTable": "NO SLIDER ADDED YET !",
    },
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 30, 50], [10, 20, 30, 50]],
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sAjaxSource": root_domain+'controller/slider_controller.php',

    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        aoData.push( { "name": "mode", "value": "fetch" } );
    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
        $('.ttip, [data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    }
}).fnSetFilteringDelay();

//Search input style
$('.dataTables_filter input').addClass('form-control').attr('placeholder','Search');
$('.dataTables_length select').addClass('form-control');
```

**controller.php**

```
<?php
include('../model/slider_model.php');

class slider_controller
{
    public function fetch()
    {
        //echo "hey";
        $obj = new model();
        $sel = $obj->fetch();
        return $sel;
    }

}
?>
```

**model.php**

```
<?php
class model
{
public function fetch()
    {
            //echo "abc";
            if(strtolower($_POST['mode']) == "fetch") { 
            //var_dump(hey);
            echo "abc";
            $dbcon = new mysqli(SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB);     
            $appData = array();
            $i=1;
            $aColumns = array('slider_id', 'slider_name','slider_image','slider_status','cdate','slider.user_id');
            $sIndexColumn = "slider_id";
            $isWhere = array("slider_status = 0","slider.user_id in (0,$_SESSION[user_id])");
            $sTable = "tbl_slider as slider";           
            $isJOIN = array();
            $hOrder = "slider.slider_id desc";
            include('../../include/pagging.php');
            $appData = array();
            $id=1;
            foreach($sqlReturn as $row) {
                $row_data = array();
                $row_data[] = $row['sr'];
                $row_data[] = $row['slider_name'];

                if($row['slider_image'])
                {
                    $row_data[] = '<img src="'.SLIDER_VWING.$row['slider_image'].'" width="150px"/>';
                }
                else{
                    $row_data[] ='';
                }
                $row_data[] = date('d M, Y',strtotime($row['cdate']));
                if($row['user_id']=="0")
                {
                $row_data[] = '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-original-title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" href="'.ROOT.'slideredit/'.$row['slider_id'].'"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" onClick="delete_slider('.$row['slider_id'].')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                ';}
                else
                {
                    $row_data[]='';
                }
                $appData[] = $row_data;
                $id++;
            }
            $output['aaData'] = $appData;
            echo json_encode( $output );
            var_dump(( $output ));
            return json_encode($output);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I have also called controller in view file.
**view.php**

```
<?php 
include('../controller/slider_controller.php');
    session_start();
    include_once("../config/config.php");
    include_once("../config/session.php");
    $obj = new slider_controller();
    $obj->fetch();
?>
  <div class="adv-table">
                  <table  class="display table table-bordered table-striped" id="dynamic-table">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Sr. NO.</th>
                      <th>Slider Title</th>

                      <th>Slider Image</th>
                      <th>Date</th>                   
                      <th class="hidden-phone">Action</th>                    
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  </tbody>               
                  </table>
                  </div>
```

Comment: In model.php, you have `$POST['mode']`, I think you mean `$_POST['mode']`. You should also check your network tab in the browsers dev tools to see what the ajax request _acutally_ returns. And as always when things don't work, check your error log.

Comment: I tried by removing that condition.

Comment: Also.. you're echoing. var_dumping and returning the same variable. That makes the output invalid json

Comment: thats just beacuse i wanted to know what is the error.i dont thats the problem here But i tried by removing it.

Comment: Are you sure that the js is making a POST request and not a GET request? Anyway, have you looked at the actual response for the request (in the browsers network tab) and have you checked your error log? Do that and add that information to your question.

Comment: there is my whole javascript in response(network tab).